# Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to $\nu$

Tags: real-analysis

Let ($x_{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}$) be a strictly increasing sequence of real numbers (i.e.
$x_{n} < x_{n+1}, n \in \mathbb{N}$) and ($p_{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}$) be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p_{n}< \infty $ Let $\mu$  be the measure defined by $\mu(A) = \sum \{p_{n}: x_{n} \in A \}$. 
Let $\nu$ be the counting measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Find the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu$
with respect to $\nu$.

Comment: Your notation in the definition of $\mu$ doesn't really make sense. Do you mean to say $\mu(A) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n 1_A(x_n)$? If so then the Radon-Nikodym derivative is essentially trivial to see, since this function is already basically a simple function (a countably valued simple function, but close enough).

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for a measurable function $f$ so that 
$$
\mu(A) = \int_Af\,d\nu
$$
for any measurable set $A$. Take the above equation and let $A=\{x\}$, for any $x\in\mathbb R$.

**Addendum** Continuing the above thought, when $A=\{x\}$, then
$$
\mu(\{x\})=\int_{\{x\}} f\,d\nu=\int f1_{\{x\}}\,d\nu = f(x)\cdot\nu(\{x\})=f(x)
$$
Thus, once we write what $\mu(\{x\})$ is, we have a formula for $f(x)$. By definition, $\mu$ of a single element set is $p_n$ if that element is $x_n$, and 0 otherwise. Thus,
$$
\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}=f(x)=\begin{cases}
p_n & x = x_n\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$